# How to turn strings on the command line into individual positional parameters

Tags: unix, command-line

My main question is how to split strings on the command line into parameters using a terminal command in Linux?
For example 
 on the command line:

`./my program hello world "10 20 30"`

The parameters are set as:

$1 = hello

$2 = world

$3 = 10 20 30

But I want:

$1 = hello

$2 = world

$3 = 10

$4 = 20

$5 = 30

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Is this for a program you wrote? Do you have the option to change how the parameters are passed in? If you do, you can just remove the quotes to separate the numbers.

Comment: I can't do that because that is the expected input from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the positional parameters `$@` by using the [set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_014_011) builtin.  If you do [not double-quote `$@`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), the shell will word-split it producing the behavior you desire:

```
$ cat my_program.sh
#! /bin/sh
i=1
for PARAM; do
  echo "$i = $PARAM";
  i=$(( $i + 1 ));
done

set -- $@
echo "Reset \$@ with word-split params"

i=1
for PARAM; do
  echo "$i = $PARAM";
  i=$(( $i + 1 ));
done

$ sh ./my_program.sh foo bar "baz buz"
1 = foo
2 = bar
3 = baz buz
Reset $@ with word-split params
1 = foo
2 = bar
3 = baz
4 = buz
```

As an aside, I find it mildly surprising that you *want* to do this.  Many shell programmers are frustrated by the shell's easy, accidental word-splitting — they get "John", "Smith" when they wanted to preserve "John Smith" — but it seems to be your requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs`:

```
echo "10 20 30" | xargs ./my_program hello world
```

> **xargs** is a command on Unix and most Unix-like operating systems used
>   to build and execute command lines from standard input. Commands such as 
>   grep and awk can accept the standard input as a parameter, or argument
>   by using a pipe. However, others such as cp and echo disregard the
>   standard input stream and rely solely on the arguments found after the
>   command. Additionally, under the Linux kernel before version 2.6.23,
>   and under many other Unix-like systems, arbitrarily long lists of
>   parameters cannot be passed to a command,[1] so xargs breaks the list
>   of arguments into sublists small enough to be acceptable.

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs))

Comment: for this to work i have to put it on the command line. How would i code `echo "10 20 30" | xargs ./my_program hello world` into a program?

Comment: You can put it directly in your bash script. Try it and see that it works.